# When I text my friend who has my old iPhone I get the same text sent to my new iPhone as well.

Tags: ios, messages, photo-stream

I reset my phone settings, but I think my info is still on there.  We already set up her information on the 4s.

How do I fix this problem without going thru the same process?

She also gets my photos uploaded to her phone with photo stream.  I had to turn off photostream on her phone so she doesn't get them.

Comment: Which Apple ID was used to register this device?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your friend's iPhone is still connected to your Apple ID. Tell her to go to Settings > iCloud > scroll to the bottom and tap 'Delete this account'

Better yet, have her restore from iTunes to get a completely fresh install — That's your best bet to remove all your information from the phone